# Write to a sysfs node, causing the system always write to the node

Tags: linux, kernel, sysfs

I locally wirte a module to test function/feature, And I create follow node info:

```
/sys/class/dbc/dbc # ls -l
total 0
-rw------- 1 root root 4096 2021-10-08 21:52 dbc_backlight
-rw------- 1 root root 4096 2021-10-08 22:30 dbc_pwm_max
-rw------- 1 root root 4096 2021-10-08 22:30 dbc_pwm_min
-rw------- 1 root root 4096 2021-10-08 21:52 dbc_setting
-rw------- 1 root root 4096 2021-10-08 21:52 dbc_thread_enable
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2021-10-08 22:30 dev
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 2021-10-08 22:30 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 2021-10-08 22:30 subsystem -> ../../../../class/dbc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 2021-10-08 22:30 uevent
```

when I echo right value to dbc_backlight node, can normally work, but when I write error value to dbc_backlight node, will result always write, info is follow:
node source code is follow:

```
static ssize_t dbc_backlight_store(struct device *dev,
    struct device_attribute *attr,
    const char *buf, size_t count)
{
    unsigned int DBC_BACKLIGHT = 0;
    int readCount = 0;
 
    printk("===========Set DBC Backlight========\n");
    readCount = sscanf(buf, "%d", &DBC_BACKLIGHT);
    if (readCount != 1)
    {
       printk("[ERROR] cannot read DBC_BACKLIGHT from [%s] \n", buf);
       return 0;
    }
    if (DBC_BACKLIGHT > 100)
    {
       printk("Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=%d \n", DBC_BACKLIGHT);
       return 0;
    }
 
    printk("Set Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=%d success\n", DBC_BACKLIGHT);
    m_u8BacklightSetting = DBC_BACKLIGHT;
 
    SetActiveBacklightSwitch(m_eActiveBackLight, m_u8BacklightSetting);
 
    return count;
}
```

abnormal status dmesg log info is:

```
[ 2562.416693] ===========Set DBC Backlight========
[ 2562.416739] Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=101 
[ 2562.416786] ===========Set DBC Backlight========
[ 2562.416832] Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=101 
[ 2562.416878] ===========Set DBC Backlight========
[ 2562.416960] Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=101 
[ 2562.417006] ===========Set DBC Backlight========
[ 2562.417089] Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=101 
[ 2562.417135] ===========Set DBC Backlight========
[ 2562.417181] Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=101 
[ 2562.417265] ===========Set DBC Backlight========
[ 2562.417309] Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=101 
[ 2562.417391] ===========Set DBC Backlight========
[ 2562.417436] Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=101 
[ 2562.417481] ===========Set DBC Backlight========
[ 2562.417564] Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=101
```

the log will always running and can't stop, otherwise, kill -9 pid can kill(kill pid can't kill it), top info is follow:

```
Tasks: 410 total,   2 running, 349 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie                                                                    
Mem:   1694992k total,  1583088k used,   111904k free,    12844k buffers                                                                
Swap:   409596k total,    13056k used,   396540k free,   732388k cached                                                                 
400%cpu   6%user 102%nice 135%sys 157%idle   0%iow   0%irq   0%sirq   0%host                                                            
  PID USER         PR  NI VIRT  RES  SHR S[%CPU] %MEM     TIME+ ARGS                                                                    
 2272 logd         30  10  34M 9.4M 4.1M S  152   0.5   2:29.57 logd
10181 root         20   0 4.4M 2.3M 1.9M R 98.6   0.1   1:33.14 sh -
```

kill -9 10181 can stop thread running.

I don't know why always write the node(dbc_backlight), please help me.

And locally, I do follow modify, the problem will not reproduce:

```
    printk("===========Set DBC Backlight========\n");
    readCount = sscanf(buf, "%d", &DBC_BACKLIGHT);
    if (readCount != 1)
    {
       printk("[ERROR] cannot read DBC_BACKLIGHT from [%s] \n", buf);
       return 0;
    }
    if (DBC_BACKLIGHT > 100)
    {
       printk("Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=%d \n", DBC_BACKLIGHT);
       return 0;
    }

//modify follow will fix it the problem
    printk("===========Set DBC Backlight========\n");
    readCount = sscanf(buf, "%d", &DBC_BACKLIGHT);
    if (readCount != 1)
    {
       printk("[ERROR] cannot read DBC_BACKLIGHT from [%s] \n", buf);
       return -EINVAL; //........
    }
    if (DBC_BACKLIGHT > 100)
    {
       printk("Invalid Parameter DBC_BACKLIGHT=%d \n", DBC_BACKLIGHT);
       return -EINVAL;........
    }
```

Do you know why? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On success, `.store` function should return **number of characters** written.

In fail, it should return **negative error code**.

Returning 0 (`return 0;`) from that function is **incorrect**.

As you correctly noted, you can use `return -EINVAL;` for indicate that input is invalid.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but return 0, why always write the node?

Comment: On "low-level", the `write` system call is processed by `.write` function in `struct file_operations`. The return value of that function (if non-negative) is interpreted as number of bytes which has been written. If that number is lower than the number of bytes a user passes to the system call, then the call will be repeated with the rest number of bytes. As you can guess, in case of returning 0, "rest number of bytes" are the same as original number, so the system call is executed once more. A `.store` function differs from the `.write` one, but they share some semantic.

Comment: thanks your very much, I found kernel source code, but I can't find the source code of root cause(If that number is lower than the number of bytes a user passes to the system call, then the call will be repeated with the rest number of bytes.)? Could you please help to point the source code place? thanks